# Display text only once per session in .net

Tags: asp.net, session, session-cookies

I have a text to be displayed to user only once per session i.e. only the first time they try to open a page. If they try to open again they are not supposed to see that text.

If they close the browser and open it again they should be able to see the text again.
I wanted to use session, but I am not sure how to use it.

I tried to use cookie which worked, but what if cookie is disabled, I guess this wont work. so I decided to go with Sessions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define `OnSessionStart` Event In `Global.asax`...like this...

```
 void Session_OnStart(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
       Session["showmessage"]="Show";
        }
```

On `pageLoad` or Event where you want to check... Check Session...if you want to show your text in label do like this...

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
if(Session["showmessage"].ToString()=="Show")
{
Label1.Text="Message";//i Supposed you wana Show Message in Label.You Can Write your Code to Show Message wherever you wnat show.
Session["showmessage"]=Not Show";//To Display Message Only One Time.
}
```

**Note-:** It will Display Message Every Time Your Session Expired.